# Programa de filtrar números impares em uma lista de numeros

Tags: programação-funcional, haskell

Escrevi um script em haskell pra encontrar filtrar os números impares de um lista e mostra-los na tela, mas fico recebendo um erro na hora de exibir os resultados..

```
impares[] =[]
impares(x:xs) 
        |(mod(x 2)==0) = impares xs
        |otherwise = x:(impares xs)
```

o erro é o seguinte:

```
no instance for (show (a10 -> a0)) arising from a use of 'print'
```

Aparentemente nao tem nada de errado no meu codigo, mas nao consigo executar esse programa! Alguem pode dar uma luz?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O erro esta na forma como usas o operador `mod`. Altera a definição da tua função para

```
impares [] = []
impares (x:xs) 
        | x `mod` 2 == 0 = impares xs
        | otherwise      = x:(impares xs)
```

Ou se pretenderes usar a notação prefixa podes escrever assim:

```
impares [] = []
impares (x:xs) 
        | mod x 2 == 0 = impares xs
        | otherwise    = x:(impares xs)
```

Esta função poderia ainda ser definida usando apenas funções do modulo Prelude.Uma alternativa seria:

```
impares = filter odd
```

Comment: Gratidão! agora me liguei como eh!

Comment: `impares = filter odd` é muito elegante. Boa sugestão.